# How do /** and /* differ in terms of directory navigation in Grunt?

Tags: directory, gruntjs, wildcard-expansion

This is quite an easy one for you guys, but I can't find a definitive/formal answer to this question.

Suppose we are in directory A. Then,

"A/* " probably means: Every file and folder directly inside A.

"A/** " then may mean: Every file and folder inside A, and every file and folder directly inside every child that is directly inside A. (Basically, an extension of /* operator that traverses one level deeper of the root folder? aka "/** " = "/* /* " )

My "directly inside" terminology might be wrong. May be its better to say "direct child" or something, but you get the idea.

Then, what does "A/**/* " mean? Is it equal to "A/* /* /* " ?

Although this seems basic, its quite confusing when I don't have a formal definition of the operators.

I'm currently using Javascript and trying to modify a Gruntfile. But I guess these operators may come up in any context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This behavior is not intrinsic to JavaScript and is *not* related to any operators: as far as JavaScript is concerned, it is just a string.

The handling of such glob expansion is determined by the *specific* library/consumer. For gruntjs it is covered in [Grunt Globbing Patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns):

> It is often impractical to specify all source filepaths individually, so Grunt supports filename expansion (also know as globbing) via the built-in node-glob and minimatch libraries ..
>
> - `*` matches any number of characters, but not `/`
> - `**` matches any number of characters, including `/`, as long as it's the only thing in a path part
>
> All most people need to know is that `foo/*.js` will match all files ending with .js in the foo/ subdirectory, but `foo/**/*.js` will match all files ending with .js in the foo/ subdirectory and *all* of its subdirectories.

As such (but refer to the specific documentation!), `/**/` generally means "match any depth of directories" and `/*/` or `/*` means "match a single directory or file part".

---

The gruntjs documentation is a bit vague on the specific mechanics of `**` in the standard `"/**/*.x"` pattern, but referring to [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) says:

> If a "globstar" (`**`) is *alone in a path portion*, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories.
>
> [.. The double-star character] is supported in the manner of bsdglob and bash 4.3, where `**` *only* has special significance if it is the only thing in a path part. That is, `a/**/b` will match `a/x/y/b`, but `a/**b` will not.

Using this knowledge we get the equivalency (when used as a path component), of `A/**/f` with `A/f`, `A/*/f`, `A/*/*/f`, etc for every number of intermediate directories.

Comment: Oh I see better now, thanks.  But I don't get this: why do I need A/**/* instead of A/** ?      The way I see it, A/** can mean any file inside A and inside its subdirectories ?

Comment: @batilc Updated the answer for the specific case.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I need one more specific clarification about this, because I think I understand the explanation you provide, but it is inconsistent with what I have in my hand. I'm pretty new in grunt, so I may be wrong with my assumption: I have this line: ......files: [{ expand: true, cwd: 'src/', src: ['img/**'], dest: 'www/' }].....    So what I was expecting that Its going to copy any file under img. However, if it is not matching any files, what does it do then? Return only the sub-folders and leave the file-search to grunt inside those sub-folders?

Comment: Use `"img/**/*"` to copy every file recursively. Without the trailing `/*` the globstar is *not* in a "path component" and thus does not expand to subdirectories as desired.

Comment: Actually that line does copy every folder and file under "img" to "www".   So my guess is that grunt only wants the folders-list to be copied, not the files itself.

Comment: @batilc Both approaches "should" work (but I'm not on node right now, so I can't test it and could be wrong). I would use the specific directory `"img"`, and let normal copy recursion work, if does accomplish the desired goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you see `A/**/*` that means to recursively search all the way down the tree of every folder under folder `A`. For more information look up basic linux style file commands.

Comment: A/**/*.js then means that every js file inside every sub-folder of A, including the A folder itself?  Btw cant still find a legitimate documentation of this :/

Comment: yes, `**/*.js` will match any `.js` file under the directory. The `*` is a wildcard matcher for file manipulation. `**` is a special wildcard that means `every directory starting here` so it won't match file names.